# How to get value from javascript function in java in wicket

Tags: javascript, java, wicket

I am able to call javascript function from java file and also able to see the output of it

I am getting it in the alert using the below code but does not know how to store it in java object,

```
target.appendJavascript("s=$('#signature').jSignature('getData')");
target.appendJavascript("alert(s)");
```

In html I have one java script file imported.
`"jSignature('getData')"` is function inside it.

This `jSignature` actually returns the value of the signature of user.

Any idea how to store the output of function?

Comment: hard to say without wider Wicket context (sources)

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript added to the Ajax response is `target.appendJavaScript()` (and `prependJavaScript()` too) is executed via `eval()`, so even if you assign the result to a variable it will be scoped to the namespace of the eval.

You could "assign" the result to some pre-existing JS object in the DOM though, e.g. `window.myVar = ...`.

You could use `window.myVar` once the Ajax call is completed. The Ajax calls are asynchronous so you may need to use the callbacks (success, failure, complete) to be notified when the call is done.

Comment: I am assigning the required value(output) to one of the hidden field variable but not sure how to get it in the wicket.

Comment: I don't understand you comment. Please re-phrase.

Comment: In my HTML I have one hidden field and its corresponding id with me. Onclick of submit button I am calling $('#signature').jSignature('getData') function and assigning the output of it to that hidden field. Is there any way I can get my value of this hidden filed using the form(arg1). The code is like   
@Override
protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form arg1) {
///code to get hidden field value.
}

Comment: It would be also good if you can explain how to use window.var in wicket

Comment: You cannot use `window.myVar` in Wicket because this is a JavaScript variable living in the browser and Wicket lives in the (Java) server. If the value is assigned to a hidden field then it will be submitting with the form and you can read it with `getRequest().getRequestParameters().getParameterValue("theNameOfTheHiddenField")`

Comment: Do not have getRequest().getRequestParameters().getParameterValue() method. May be it is because of the difference in version. We are using 1.3.4.

I using getRequest().getRequestParameters().getParameters().get("hiddenObject") to get the value. But even using this I am getting null value.

Comment: 1.3.4 is older than me. I cannot help you! Sorry!